# What law is applicable in arbitration?

Tags: united-states, arbitration

I am representing myself in arbitration proceedings against a large business.

The American Arbitration Association is orchestrating the proceedings and has stated that the [Consumer Arbitration Rules](https://www.adr.org/sites/default/files/Consumer-Rules-Web.pdf) apply.

The rules do not give any guidance on important non-procedural elements: the standard of proof (is it akin to civil? criminal?), determination of relevant law, what cases can be cited, admissibility of evidence, etc. Where can I find answers to these questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The rules do not give any guidance on important non-procedural
> elements: the standard of proof (is it akin to civil? criminal?),
> determination of relevant law, what cases can be cited, admissibility
> of evidence, etc. Where can I find answers to these questions?

Generally, arbitrators apply the substantive law of the jurisdiction applicable to the dispute, and the procedural rules of the arbitration forum, and their own views when neither applies.

But this is not a legally enforceable obligation of an arbitrator. An arbitrator can grossly disregard the law and need not follow any rules of evidence other than to allow you to present all relevant evidence. If the arbitrator wants to apply the Pirate Code of a Hollywood Film, the arbitrator is within his or her authority to do so and will not be reversed for doing so when the prevailing party seeks to have the award confirmed.

Also, while you can seek to set aside an arbitration for particularized bias in a given case, you generally cannot do so out of systemic bias in favor of the party drafting the arbitration clause, even though that is well established empirically.

Comment: This is not strictly true. When the parties have agreed (which they may have in the arbitration agreement or subsequently) on a methodology, the arbitrator must follow it or a court will overturn the award. When they have agreed then the arbitrator has discretion.

Comment: @DaleM At least under U.S. law and the federal arbitration act, the failure of the arbitrator to follow the agreed rules is basically unreviewable.

Comment: under the various Commercial Arbitration Acts in Australia it’s one of the (very few) grounds for appeal.

Comment: It looks like according to [some sources](http://arbitrationblog.kluwerarbitration.com/2019/11/12/is-manifest-disregard-alive-and-well-in-the-second-circuit-a-remand-to-find-out/), it's a giant mess of a circuit split.  Do you know if the law around manifest disregard has developed further since then?

Comment: @RyanM The law is now almost uniform that manifest disregard isn't a basis for overturning an arbitration award in the U.S., at least if the manifest disregard doesn't go to the scope of the issues to be decided in arbitration (e.g. if the arbitration said "fee disputes only" but the ruling resolved a non-fee related dispute between the parties, that might still be modifiable or vacated). I would have little doubt that SCOTUS would reverse the 2nd Circuit holding that the exception exists.

Comment: FWIW, I asked my particular arbitrator "Should a claim reference to substantive law only? Or will you allow references to general principles of equity and fairness?" and they replied "I will consider substantive law and equity/fairness".

Comment: @ohwilleke is the 'what would scotus or a state high court hold' framework of approaching legal questions the standard one for practicing lawyers today?

Comment: Is it fair to say that, in a consumer dispute, this is could be a very good reason to pursue arbitration instead of small claims court? My understanding is that in the latter forum, it isn't enough for the consumer to convince the judge that the business' behavior was simply unfair--they must prove that it was illegal.

Comment: @JoshJohnson The systemic bias of the arbitrators in consumer arbitration and lack of a right to appeal overwhelm all other considerations.

Comment: Makes sense. Worth noting that my specific arbitration agreement notes "A party can file a written appeal to the arbitration administrator within 30 days after an award is issued. The appeal will proceed before a panel of three neutral arbitrators designated by the same arbitration administrator." so the right to appeal exists in at least some cases.

Comment: @JoshJohnson Unusual, and still no recourse to the courts for not following the law.